# Django REST PATCH request field is required problem

Tags: python, html, django, django-rest-framework, insert-update

I have a **Student** model. And I want to update some specific fields. But when I go to update one or two fields but the other field value is as it is then which fields are not changing those fields show this error** "This field is required.". **

**Here is my model.**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    teacher=models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    level=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**And here are my views**

```
class StudentUpdateDelete(APIView): 
    def patch(self, request, id):
        student=Student.objects.filter(pk=id).first()
        serializer=StudentSerializer(student, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Avobe model has 3 fields but I want to change only the **name** field using patch methods.

[here is postman request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSvYo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update specific field with the `PATCH` method, set `partial=True` when you are initializing the `serializer`.

So, for your view it would be:

```
class StudentUpdateDelete(APIView): 
    def patch(self, request, id):
        student=Student.objects.filter(pk=id).first()
        serializer=StudentSerializer(student, data=request.data, partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```